# Conflicting Logrotate Permissions

Tags: apache-2.4, permissions, ubuntu-16.04, logrotate

I've got a folder full of log files, and I'm using `logrotate` to rotate them.

Until recently, I only had Apache log files in there - access.log and error.log. I've added a new log from a daemon, daemon.log. The daemon log is being written by a daemon running under the `www-data` user.

When it runs, `logrotate` creates a new log, with permissions of `640`, user `root` and group `adm`. Apache can write to the access and error logs with these permissions, but my daemon, running as `www-data`, can't.

As I see it, there are a few options:

1. Change the `logrotate` config to manually specify which log files are given which permissions. But this means if I add a new log file, I need to remember to configure `logrotate` to manage it.
2. Modify the `logrotate` script to somehow create an exception for the daemon.log file. Is that even possible?
3. Move the daemon log to a new folder, with a separate `logrotate` script to manage log files in that new folder. Simple enough, but I'd like to keep all my logs together if I can.
4. Set `logrotate` to create the files under a different user and group. Seems like this would risk missing log information.
5. Add the `www-data` user to the `adm` group, and set permissions to `660`. I don't like the idea of giving the `www-data` user access to other stuff unintentionally.
6. Set permissions on the log files to `666`. Seems like a crude solution.

None of those is ideal, and I'm pretty sure a couple are terrible. Is there another option, or is one of these my best bet? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The standard answer is to make logrotate create the files with the ownership that the process will need in order to write to them. (I do not see why that would risk missing log information; perhaps you could elaborate on why you think this is a risk.)

You do that by adding the line

```
create owner group
```

to the relevant bit of logrotate config. If you want to have the files with a particular permission, you add

```
create mode owner group
```

instead.

Example:

```
create 644 www-data www-data
```

Comment: The logrotate config handles both the apache logs and the daemon logs, all in the same folder. The apache logrotate script uses `create 640 root adm`. If I change to `www-data www-data`, I'd presumably stop apache being able to write to its logs? Or would it not matter if Apache is writing log files as root?

Comment: @DaveChild This is why it's a really good thing to include your config in your question... I'd recommend either putting the different logs in a different directory, or changing your config to look at filenams and not just directory.